# VS2008 XML Code Snippets Not Working

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2008, xslt, code-snippets

I added a folder to the Code Snippets Manager, opened the Parent.snippet file for use as a template, edited it as below, and saved it to my "XML Snippets" folder.

Now, whenever I try to use a snippet, the editor inserts a comment (<!-- -->) instead of the snippet contents... FOR ANY snippet, the VS2008 original snippets, my snippet - doesn't matter.  I did not edit or alter the original snippets in any way.

When I removed the folder from the Code Snippets Manager (thinking I messed something up, and this would bring back the functionality of the OEM snippets) the functionality was NOT restored.  I restarted VS2008, to no avail.  I am at a loss here.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT1:**

Tried reinstalling VSTS2008 SP1, no help.  any TYPED code snippet (in XML, at least) renders as a comment tag when tab is pressed; however, if I type the shortcut Ctrl+K, Ctrl+S - all snippets are listed as expected and operate just fine if selected from the dropdown menu.

**EDIT2:**

Verified that TYPED **and** SHORTCUT KEY code snippets work normally in C#

**EDIT3:**

Tried deleting the entire XML snippets folder and it's snippetsIndex.xml file, reinstalling VSTS2008 SP1 (again) to no avail.  Also tried resetting all VS settings back to default.  Still getting crappy little comment tag.

Comment: Voted to close as no longer relevant - really no good info in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, uninstalled VS2008, deleted every related directory I could find, reinstalled it - and it works now.  I hate crap with no explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Visual Studio 2008 SP1? There were substantial changes made to the XML Editor in that release. I don't recall whether XML Code Snippets were part of it.